# Salvar REQUESTS AJAX para serem executados depois

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

Uso jQuery e a biblioteca Ajax para fazer REQUESTS.

Existe uma forma de salvar REQUESTS, segue o exemplo..

O usuário tá lá mexendo e derrepente a conexão cai e o usuário o não percebe.. E continua fazendo o que fazia.. e derrepente ele envia uma requisição, óbvio essa requisição não será enviada mas como salvar essa requisição para quando a internet voltar ela ser enviada e o usuário não perder seu conteúdo..

Esse REQUEST tem que ser salvo e ser imune a refresh de página, para que mesmo se ele fechar a página, quando ele voltar os requests pendentes serão enviados.

Comment: amigo, até é possível fazer isto com `localStorage`, você poderia fazer um wrapper para a chamada `$.ajax` com `timeout`, e no `error` do `$.ajax` você colocaria a requisição em uma `fila` no `localStorage`, então você teria um `window.setInterval` lendo esta `fila` e reenviando o `request`, mas vou logo te adiantar que esta abordagem vai lhe trazer mais problemas que benefícios.

Comment: @TobyMosque por que ocasionaria mais erros que soluções ?

Comment: Imagine um problema o canal de transporte no retorno da requisição, para o servidor está tudo ok, mas o browser não recebeu nenhuma resposta, então neste caso você iria reenviar o request. isto pode acabar gerando duplicidade dos dados, outro ponto, o usuario envia um formulario, deu timeout, mas como você colocou o request na pool você deu ao usuario uma mensagem de "OK", porem antes que a conexão fosse restabelecida o usuário limpou o localStorage, então temos uma mensagem de sucesso em um cenário de erro.

Comment: então talvez seja melhor, apenas informar um erro na comunicação, então o usuário pode realizar alguma consulta no sistema ou reenviar os dados.

Comment: @TobyMosque compreendo, mas essa página seria pra uso offline (cache Manifest) então seria essencial isso.. Tentarei pensar em algo.

Comment: Neste caso, acho que o ideal seria desenvolver um [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), acredito que desta forma você pode usar um banco sqlite, então teria um "serviço" fazendo a sincronização dos dados quando a conexão estiver disponível.

Comment: se não for uma quantidade grande de dados, pode salvar em cookies..  Outro local para salvar é localstorage , porém disponível em browsers com versões mais recentes somente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar log da sua aplicação, abaixo um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
$(function() {

  $('#submit_button').on('click', function() {
    var data = {teste: 'teste'};
      $.ajax({
         url: "send_data.php",
         data: data,
         method: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function( data ) {
             $('#msg').html("enviando dados...");
         }
      }).done(function( data ) {
             var msg = $.parseJSON(data);
             $('#msg').html(msg);
      }).fail(function(error) {
         //redireciona e salva o log do erro
         window.location.href='event_log_register.php?data_expected=data:,' + 
         data.responseJSON +
         '&data_error=' +
         error.responseJSON +
         '&redirect=true';

      }).always(function() {
         $('#msg').html("Envio concluído!");
      });
   });
});
```

Copie e cole o texto abaixo no seu navegador:
data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8=